# The Correct Ordering of Script and Style Files in header

Tags: javascript, button, datatable

I use the scripts and style files below and so with that queue the colvis button doesnt open..

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="preconnect">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css" >

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

But whenever I delete the ,

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

file the button works but style is gone this time...

What is my mistake , any idea?

[THAT BUTTON NOT WORKING IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niQ5l.png)

[THAT BUTTON STYLE GONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvppk.png)

Answer (score 0):

AT last I found the correct one below..

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
```